# SQL Server tables replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster-computing

Is it possible to replicate 2 SQL Servers on table level? (I want to replicate only few tables, not all DB). Both SQL Servers work on different physical servers and should synchronize a few tables.

If it is possible, how to avoid conflicts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use MERGE Replication provided both source and destination table names should be same.I guess transactional replication might support if table names are different.